# asp.net url rewrite based on part of url?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Currently my urls look like this:
www.mysite.com/venues/<venueid>/<venuename>
e.g.
www.mysite.com/venues/342/myvenue

it's quite easy creating a rewrite url for this by checking for the occurence of "venues"

```
<rule name="view venue">
<match url="^venues/([0-9]+)?/??([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="locationdetails.aspx?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

But for a NEW site I want my URLS to look like this:
    www.mysite.com/<venuename>-<venueid>
e.g.
  www.mysite.com/myvenue-342

I though of creating rewrite rules that check on a number in the url and use that as the venue id, but that would cause an issue if the venue venuename and this friendlyurl would contain a number, e.g. "pier 39" would then become "pier-39-342", or is there a way to capture the last id in the friendly url (so the id after the last dash) and use that as the parameter for R:1?

I already looked at this blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/04/20/url-parts-available-to-url-rewrite-rules.aspx which seems to cover my needs, but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule seems to do what I need:

```
    <rule name="venue details">
      <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9-]+)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="locationdetails.aspx?id={R:2}&amp;furl={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```